# Git installation hell on Linux

Tags: linux, git, redmine

I have a bitnami - redmine virtual machine with Redmine 3.0.1.

This came with Git pre-installed, version 1.9.5. I am now trying to update it, but I have some big difficulties.

apt-get installs git in `/usr/bin/git` but my current git path (which git) is `opt/bitnami/git/bin/git`

If I go in `/usr/bin` and type `./git --version` I get the correct latest version, but if I just do `git --version` either from there or anywhere else I get the old version.

How do I get rid of the old version, or update it? I need the new version for a redmine plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: If you installed a “stack-in-one” package or however you want to call it, it should only be upgraded as a whole. Why do you think you need a more recent version of Git?

Comment: I concur with this: a bitnami stack should NOT be upgraded through git, you may find instructions here: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine#How_to_upgrade_Redmine.3f ; as for Redmine general upgrade instructions, they're described here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade and they don't mention git neither (using git/svn as an upgrade path is reserved to advanced usages/developers imho)

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe I've been unclear. I'm not trying to upgrade the bitnami stack THROUGH git. I am trying to upgrade GIT, meaning, the GIT client command line. There is 1.9.5 installed but the "Scm Creator" plugin requires a higher version, I think 2.0 or higher.

Comment: @DanielB The "Scm Creator" plugin doesn't work with git 1.9.5, it highlights it with a red error icon. It seems like it needs 2.0+ to work. I need it to keep the local bare repositories on the redmine server automatically in sync with our github repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume `opt/bitnami/git/bin` is higher in your `PATH` than `/usr/bin`.  Check `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc` for the `/opt/bitnami/...` path entry and either demote it to the end of `PATH`, or remove it entirely if you don't want to use the old version at all.

Comment: could also ln -s to /opt/.....

Comment: I'm a bit of linux ignorant here... that ln -s needs a little more explanation... the profile or bashrc part is clear though. Now I'm home I'll try tomorrow as soon as I get back to work, thanks

Comment: `ln -s` is the command to create a symbolic link, which is very, very, very approximately like a Windows 'shortcut'. Run `man ln` for more information.  Fixing `PATH` seems like a cleaner solution to me. `ln -s` would require getting the `/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git` executable out of the way first, such as by renaming it `git.deactivated.bin` or something, and then creating the symbolic link in its place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your solution and it indeed worked, although redmine keeps using the version of git installed in its stack. I guess it's not using the path. I'll mark this as answer anyway because you indeed solved the problem as I asked it here.

Comment: @MatteoMosca: Interesting. It must have a git path stored internally somewhere.  Might be a configuration file somewhere you could tweak.